# Unauthorized readbody=true when posting message to hangout chat room with webhook

Tags: ruby, webhooks, google-hangouts

Trying to post a message to a `hangout chat room`. I've generated a webhook for the room and used it as uri in the following code. The rest are basic net/http stuff.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

message = 'hello'

# prep and send the http request 
uri = URI.parse("https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAcroWtl4/messages?key=abc&token=xyz")

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request.body = '"content":[{"type":"text","text":"'+message+'"}]'
req_options = { use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https" }

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
puts response.inspect
```

The response contains the following text.

```
#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>
```

Is there something wrong with the request body?

Edit: key and token changed in the question.

This same code worked with stride rooms, the only difference is that it had

```
request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{access_token}"
```

Since the token is already in the uri I figured this would not be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

message = 'hello'

# prep and send the http request 
uri = URI.parse("//webhook")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
request.body = { text: message }.to_json

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

puts response.inspect
```

Comment: so, at the end of the day, no authentication needed?